# Can VS change variable values in my js on publish

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, ide, publish

I run VS2010 Web Developer and I set a javascript variable to one value for testing. When I publish my work, I that variable should be another value to affect the final behavior. So, in the *rumpa.js* file i have the following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var iable = "test value";
  ...}
```

However, just before I execute publish, I *manually* edit the line so it looks as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var iable = "publish value";
  ...}
```

It works great, except I often forget to change the `iable` to `"publish value"` until an unhappy customer calls.  That is not optimal development technique.

Can I somehow make VS change my source code so I won't have to?

Comment: I read your question twice and still not sure what your looking for.

Comment: He seems to want to run a makro or something that changes the value for him when he hits "publish"

Comment: @Rob Angelier I'm looking for a way for VS to automatically edit a line of code just before i publish the site and then change it back when the upload is finished. And yes, that'd be nice. But i can't see such facilities in Tools/Options etc...

Comment: So as I understand, you want your live and devel environments to have certain variables defined differently? As a general setup (this does not just apply to JS/VS/web), the simplest implementation is to have a separate config file while you define on the live and devel environments, and which is excluded from your regular "publish" process, then read your `iable` var from that config.

Comment: I see! I have to agree with @BenParsons. You could use Config Transformation Files, more information here: http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how to refer from my JS file to web.config (or any other .config for that matter). Is it available at the client side (where JS resides during run-time) at all? Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure `.config` files are useful here. I just meant you could have a separate `.js` file, in different forms for the live/local, which defines "a certain"/"an other", then not upload it with the rest of your project. This is preferable to having VS (or some other script) modifying your code, IMO.

Comment: Ah I see the confusion now - when I said "config files" above, I was being generic - not referring to .net `.config` files - just any file which is used solely for configuration info rather than code.

Comment: OK, now i feel more familiar with what's going on here, haha. At first it felt like i'm missing something obvious. @RobAngelier should put his link to the blog as an answer so i can check it as an approved reply. I haven't tested it yet but fter i've read a portion of it, i'm confident that's the how-to i was looking for.

Comment: You can use the variable flag DEBUG. During development DEBUG is true. For publish it is false. VS has DEBUG, RELEASE flags predefined. Leverage them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use config transformation files. This way you can have different settings for each publish profile. More info can be found here: http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/02/17/ASPNET-40-Part-4-Config-Transformation-Files.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The link referenced in Rob Angelier's answer isn't working for me. Since I was looking for the same issue today, I found you can use #DEBUG:

```
#if DEBUG
    var iable = "test value";
#else
    var iable = "publish value";
#endif
```

However I sometimes need to publish a debug build to the server which this method does not allow for. So you can check for the server name:

```
var iable;
if (window.location.hostname=="localhost")
{
    var iable = "test value";
} else
{
    var iable = "publish value";
}
```

Or in Angular I use a service as:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services", ["ngResource"])
        .constant("appSettings",
        {
            commonsetting: false,
        });

    if (window.location.hostname=="localhost")
    {
        // local dev settings
        angular
            .module("common.services", ["ngResource"])
            .constant("appSettings",
            {
                iable = "test value";
            });
    } else
    {
        // remote settings
        angular
            .module("common.services", ["ngResource"])
            .constant("appSettings",
            {
                var iable = "publish value";
            });
    }
}());
```

Hopefully this will save someone some time.